# slides scrolls when any part of the website is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, swiper.js

I am working on a page with slides, using swiper.js

The slides should only change when the down arrow is clicked, **NOT** when any other element on the page is clicked, neither the text or the background of the page, but strangely, when other elements are clicked, the slides are changing, I don't understand why.

Here is a video where I show what happens, it can be seen clearly when I click on the "seasons of change" section and then the slide changes up, also in the last section, when I click on several words and then the slide changes again upwards:
https://z-testing.000webhostapp.com/_swiper/video.webm

Here is a demo of the website:
https://z-testing.000webhostapp.com/_swiper/

This is my code:

```
$(window).load(function() {

  var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    direction: 'vertical',
    slidesPerView: 1,
    spaceBetween: -1,
    mousewheel: true,
    preventClicks: true,
    allowTouchMove: true,
    preventClicksPropagation: true
  });

  // next slide
  $(".scrolldown").on("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      swiper.slideNext();
      return !1;
  });

});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="swiper-container swiper-container-home">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <article class="swiper-slide">
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `allowTouchMove` to false and the random clicking seems to disappear. I assume that some clicks are interpreted as touchmove by the browser when you move the cursor while clicking.

Checkout this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Lundstromski/pen/VwazPeB) where `allowTouchMove` is set to "false".